# Does there exist a reversible monoid that fails to be Dedekind-finite?

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, monoid

Call a ring with unity

- *reversible* iff $xy = 0$ implies $yx = 0$.
- *Dedekind-finite* iff $xy = 1$ implies $yx = 1$.

It is proved [here](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/tag/reversible-ring/) that every reversible ring is Dedekind-finite.

Now clearly, the above definitions make sense for an arbitrary monoid with an absorbing element $0$ satisfying $x0 = 0$ and $0x = 0$. Call such a structure a *monoid with zero*.

Does there exist a reversible monoid with zero that fails to be Dedekind-finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the [bicyclic monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclic_semigroup) B and add a zero. The resulting monoid is a reversible monoid with zero that fails to be Dedekind-finite.

Comment: Very nice example !!